# Activating bluetooth in Android 9 Pie

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-9.0-pie

I have been activating bluetooth in my app for years doing this simple code:

```
BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if (btAdapter.isEnabled() == false) 
   btAdapter.enable()
```

But now, with Android 9, the System displays a screen to the user with the text "The app xxx is trying to enable bluetooth. Do you want to allow it?" (or something similar). It is very annoying for my app functionality because it works automatically in the background, so the user iteration should not be required. Is there any way to activate bluetooth in Android 9 without user interaction?

Comment: The documentation for `enable()` has had "do not use without explicit user action to turn on Bluetooth" for quite some time.

Comment: well, the user grants me his/her explicit permission to let my app activate bluetooth in his/her device because that is what he/she wants. I don't understand why Google (once again) place walls to let our apps be less functional.

Comment: My guess is that there are privacy and security concerns with apps being able to enable Bluetooth without at-the-time user consent.

Comment: mm well, I could send that "privacy" using the wifi or data connections. Don't know why "bluetooth" has to be so risky now. And by the way, they could have at least created a "dangerous" permissions to let the users tell the system that they agree giving an app the permission to activate bluetooth connections. This is really going to be a problem for my app.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, but you need to give the specific app permission to write system settings.

See my post on XDA forum:
https://forum.xda-developers.com/mate-9-pro/help/allow-to-enable-bluetooth-off-user-t3918723

Comment: May I suggest you put the 7 lines directly in the answer instead of providing a link?